# Xamarin.plugin.media 4.0.1.5 when updated throws runtime exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The target SDK Version is set to 28. Have updated my xamarin.plugin.media to 4.0.1.5.It throws runtime exception.

VS Community Edition 15.8
Xamarin.android - 9.0.0.17

Can anyone please advice?

Exeption error:

Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.psav.lighthouseuat/md53bdc6881122b82bfd2b961d262dd095c.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setAttachListener(android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout$OnAttachListener)' on a null object reference

Below are the files where the code is added upon updating the plugin.media to latest version.

1) AndroidManifest.xml

[AndroidManifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdV8N.png)

2) MainActivity.cs

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zur8W.png)

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB7wr.png)

4) Assemblyinfo.cs
[Assemblyinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ210.png)

5) Added new folder called xml into Resources folder and added a new XML file called file_paths.xml

[file_paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjSiS.png)

6) Packages.config

[Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bygIb.png)

[Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ51X.png)

Comment: you could try to delete bin and obj folders on Android project and rebuild it